Where did Sofia Kovalevskaya compare being a mathematician to being a poet?
Sofia Kovalevskaya was reported to have stated: "It is impossible to be a mathematician without being a poet in soul." Where did she state this, if at all?

Beatrice Stillman (1978) Introduction. p. 35. In Kovalevskaya, S. (1978). A Russian childhood. Springer.
Beatrice Stillman quotes a sourced letter written by Kovalevskaya in 1890 (emphasis is mine):

. . . you are surprised at my working simultaneously in literature and
in mathematics. Many people who have never had occasion to learn what
mathematics is confuse it with arithmetic and consider it a dry and
arid science. In actual fact it is the science which demands the
utmost imagination. One of the foremost mathematicians of our century
says very justly that it is impossible to be a mathematician without
also being a poet in spirit. It goes without saying that to understand
the truth of this statement one must repudiate the old prejudice by
which poets are supposed to fabricate what does not exist, and that
imagination is the same as "making things up." It seems to me that the
poet must see what others do not see, must see more deeply than other
people. And the mathematician must do the same. (VIP, 314)

The citation to VIP is explains as follows:
S. V. Kovalevskaya, Vospominaniya i pis'ma, ed. S. Ya. Shtraikh
(M, 1951), p. 485. Hereafter referred to as VIP, followed by page
numbers in the text.
It is possible that by "One of the foremost mathematicians" she is referring to Weierstrass. He wrote the following in a letter to Kovalevskaya in 1883:

[...] ein Mathematiker, der nicht etwas Poet ist, wird nimmer ein
vollkommener Mathematiker sein.

My translation:

a mathematician who is not something of a poet, will never be a complete mathematician.

The letter is reproduced in Mittag-Leffler, G. (1900). Une page de la vie de Weierstrass. Proceedings of the Second ICM, p. 149.

VIP must be this: https://www.amazon.com/Sofia-Kovalevskaia-Vospominaniia-Memoirs-S-V/dp/5780511144 I will order it, as the topics interest me greatly, and as I should freshen up on my Russian. :) Thanks!

Is S. V. Kovalevskaya, Vospominaniya i pis'ma, ed. S. Ya. Shtraikh (M, 1951) another book than the one I just ordered, perhaps?

@Georg Essi gave the quote, for those who would like to see the quote in the language of the original letter, it is

Я понимаю, что вас так удивляет, что я могу заниматься  зараз и
литературой и математикой. Многие, которым никогда  не представлялось
случая более узнать математику, смешивают  ее с арифметикою и считают
ее наукой сухой и aride *. В   сущности же это наука, требующая
наиболее фантазии, и один из  первых математиков нашего столетия
говорит совершенно верно,  что нельзя быть математиком, не будучи в то
же время и поэтом  в душе. Только, разумеется, чтобы понять верность
этого   определения, надо отказаться от старого предрассудка, что поэт
должен что-то сочинять несуществующее, что фантазия и   вымысел — это
одно и то же. Мне кажется, что поэт должен видеть  то, чего не видят
другие, видеть глубже других. И это же   должен и математик.


Very nice! Is there another source for the original Russian quote than Beatrice Stillman's book?

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal : As I said, the quote is in Georg Essi's answer, it is VIP, 314. In Russian it is С. В. Ковалевская, Воспоминания и письма, Издание исправленное и дополненное, Издательство Академии Наук СССР, 1951, отвественный редактор профессор М. В. Нечкина. редакция и комментарии С. Я. Штрайха. The quote is indeed on page 314.
